# datepicker() is transparent need some css and addeed options for months and years

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

My jquery ui datepicker() is transparent and doesn't show any months or years. Need some good css with options for month and year search..

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker();
```

Comment: datepicker shloud be packed with sme default CSS, if you don't see anything, you may have forget to add them in your project

Answer (score 0):

Download jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.css from jquery site and include the same in the page.

```
<link href="jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: Thanks but should I need to download all th images in it

Comment: Heres the link:   http://jqueryui.com/download/
The downloaded package will contain all the necessary files.